# Logstash single input and multiple output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have configured logstash to get input from one filebeat port. 
Filebeat configured with two different paths. is it possible to display logs to two different index?

Logstash input part:

```
input{
beats 
   {
     type => "stack"
     port => 5044
   }
```

Filebeat input part :

```
 prospectors:

  paths:
    - E://stack/**/*.txt
    - E://test/**/*.txt
```

Now i need to display "stack" in one index and "test" in other index. 
How to configure logstash output part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to use the knowledge of the `type` property in order to decide in which index to store the log being processed.

So your `elasticsearch` output could simply look like this, i.e. depending on the `type` value, the selected index will be different.

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   manage_template => false
   index => "%{type}"
 }
}
```

Comment: The elastic guys [don't encourage the use of type attribute](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch#sthash.GPJLwX6q.dpbs) and in addition it won't apply if you already have type field in your source (it doesn't override). So it's better to  use tags or add_field instead.

Comment: @BornToCode that blog article is more recent than my answer, but yeah...